# ¿Cómo personalizar bordes de diagrama de barras en python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Mi objetivo es conseguir el un diagrama de barras en el que se solo se muestra el borde superior de cada barra, como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando matplotlib en python para conseguirlo, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Punto 1 - Fr",fontsize = 20)
ax.set_xlabel("Demanda (X)",fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Frecuencia",fontsize = 10)
ejeX = ["7","12","18","23","25","28","30"]
altura_barras = [0.23,0.4,0.6,0.77,0.84,0.94,1.01] 
ax.bar(ejeX, altura_barras,width=0.2,color = "white",edgecolor = "green")
plt.show()
```

El cual genera el siguiente diagrama de barras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy pudiendo conseguirlo, ¿Cómo podría resulverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución un poco "tramposa" pero muy sencilla y rápida es hacer un diagrama de barras "apiladas", en las que no hay en realidad la primera "pila", solo la segunda, y todas las barras de la segunda pila tienen la misma altura, muy pequeña.

En definitiva, se trata de pasarle tu lista de datos en el argumento `bottom`, que indica la altura a que comienza cada barra, y pasarle como `height` un valor prefijado 0. Para que esas "barras" sean visibles habrá que dar un color y un grosor a sus bordes, usando `edgecolor` y `linewidth`.

Ya de paso usaré un tema oscuro para que el resultado se parezca más a la imagen que usaste como modelo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('dark_background')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Punto 1 - Fr",fontsize = 20)
ax.set_xlabel("Demanda (X)",fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Frecuencia",fontsize = 10)
ejeX = ["7","12","18","23","25","28","30"]

altura_barras = [0.23,0.4,0.6,0.77,0.84,0.94,1.01] 
ax.bar(ejeX, height=0, bottom=altura_barras, linewidth=2,
       width=0.9, edgecolor="white")

ax.set_ylim((0,1.1))
ax.set_facecolor("darkslategray")
fig.set_facecolor("darkslategray")
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

### Variante

Aunque no es lo que has pedido, creo que también hace un bonito efecto, hace más fácil leer la posición horizontal de cada barra, y además ayuda a comprender el truco usado:

```
ax.bar(ejeX, height=altura_barras, linewidth=1, edgecolor="white",
       width=1, color="white", alpha=0.05)
ax.bar(ejeX, height=0, bottom=altura_barras, linewidth=2,
       width=1, edgecolor="white")
```

[image: Segunda version]